# Запись данных в файл не происходит

Tags: c++, классы, fstream

```
CPP:
string randp = "results.txt";
fstream rout;
rout.open(randp, fstream::in | fstream::out);
    {
      rout << "Random A: " << ar << "\nRandom B: " << br << endl; 
    }
rout.close();
    initialize();
} 
H:
#ifndef Scene_h
#define Scene_h

#include <vector>
#include "Shape.h"
#include "Stick.h"


namespace DiskGame
{
    const int M = 5, N = 5;
    class Scene
    {
        std::vector<Shape*> shapes; 
        int button;           
        float angleX, angleY;  
        float mouseX, mouseY; 
        float width, height;  
        float distZ;          
        bool finish;          
        Sticks* disks[6];      
        float xStep, zStep;   
        int time;  
        int sc;
    int fields[3][3];     
                           
                         
    int xFrom, zFrom;     
    int xTo, zTo;         
public:
    Scene(float xStep, float zStep);
    ~Scene();
    void on_paint();
    void on_size(int width, int height);
    void on_mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y);
    void on_motion(int x, int y);
    void on_special(int key, int x, int y);
    void on_timer(int value);
    int dificult(int& A, int& B);

private:
    void initialize();
    void results();
    void allocatenum();
    bool moveDisk(int xFrom, int zFrom, int xTo, int zTo);
    void upDisk(int x, int z);
    void downAllDisks();
    bool findNearest(int x, int z, int& x1, int& z1);
    void shapeArr();
    float allocX(int i);
    float allocZ(int i);
};

}

#endif
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это — `fstream rout();` — совсем не объявление объекта `fstream`, как вам кажется, а *объявление функции `rout`, возвращающей объект `fstream`*.

P.S. Если намек непонятен — уберите скобки.

Comment: Спасибо, случайно объявил функцию, а не объект, проблема сейчас в том, что переменные не записываются в файл. Проверку на открытие файла я сделал, с этим всё в порядке, но записи нет.

Comment: Не верю. Потому что если файла нет - то он с флагами `fstream::in | fstream::out` не откроется... Как именно вы сделали проверку открытия?

Comment: Через rout.is_open().

Comment: А `ok` выведено?

Comment: Нашёл проблему, файл сохранялся не в зону отладки, а в неизвестное место, просто указал путь и всё заработало(перед этим создал файл с таким же именем, а как понял, что проблема в пути, после его удаления, смог всё решить).